# Storing Enums in MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, enums

I need the most clean and efficient solution for my case. I'm trying to store Marks of student in a MySQL DB. A student may be "ABSENT" or "COPY CASE", I want to store such info also in DB.

I thought of assigning codes for above case like -1 for ABSENT, -2 for COPY CASE, etc. This codes will be stored in Marks column only.

More ever, while reading them with a select query, I should get their display values i.e. `ABSENT`, `COPY CASE`, etc only.

Can all these be achieved at DB end only?

Or do I need to implement these things at Application level only?

Are there any API's available for Java for such functionality?

Answer (score 8):

mysql supports enums:

```
CREATE TABLE students (name varchar(64), mark ENUM('ABSENT','COPY CASE' ));
INSERT INTO students VALUES ('john', 'COPY CASE');
```

In java, you can treat this column as a string type column, but in the database, values are stored efficiently, and trying to store a value not contained in the enum will result in an error.

Comment: The second requirement can be satisfied by referential integrity.

Answer (score 4):

how about storing its `name()` (String version) to DB and creating it back while reading from DB using `valueOf()`

Answer (score 1):

If the enum string representations are pretty string heavy, and the database is large (checks against these enums are frequent), I'd probably map each enum to an integer constant (no, not the `ordinal()`, but your own custom integer value) and have methods on the enum to get and create an enum from these values. This way, you'll be able to store the enums pretty efficiently.

```
public enum Status {

  ABSENT(1), COPY_PASTE(2);

  int value;

  private Status(int value) {
      this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
      return this.value;
  }

  public static Status ofStatusCode(int value) {
      // retrieve status from status code
  }

}
```

Comment: Just a note that, although I do agree with Sanjay that using [numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) representation for the enum is generally more efficient than using [string types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) (performance and space wise), Enum type is an exception, it will use a 16 bit unsigned (short) internally to store values efficiently, and I never had performance problems with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of storing codes for above case like -1 for ABSENT, -2 for COPY CASE, etc. This codes will be stored in Marks column only.

I'd rather prefer having a separate column, say `status` which holds values such as
`ABSENT`, `COPY CASE` and a default value such as `APPEARED`

And marks column would stay separate.

In the view layer, you could do something like

```
if(status is 'APPEARED')
show marks field
else
show status field
```

Comment: This is definitely better that storing both marks and exam status in the same column. And you won't have (even accidentally) any wrong result in queries that find for example `AVG(mark)`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has it own [ENUM type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html). And as @Jigar Pointed out, you can use `Enum.getName` to get Java's a String representing the enum for persistence, retrieve the field from the database as a String and use `Enum.valueOf` to load the enum constant back.

You can also use `Enum.ordinal() + 1` to get a integer for persistence (MySQL also support using integer indexes directly with ENUM type) and issue a query like:

```
SELECT enum_col-1 FROM tbl_name;
```

to retrieve the ordinal back (it will retrieve -1 for rows with invalid enum values).

Plus `MyEnumType value = MyEnumType.values()[ordinal]` to convert it back to Java enum type.

Anyway, I think that the String based solution is cleaner and more elegant, plus safer on the long run (if you ever need to change the order of the java Enum, or add new enum values at the middle of the existing ones, you will thank yourself for going with String based strategy to begin with).